# How to create dynamic form with async pipe in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic angular form the data that I get from an ngRx service.

Here is the sample code.
My html template looks like

```
    <div class="padding-top-50" *ngIf="filteredParam$ | async; else loader">
      <form class="row" [formGroup]="paramForm" *ngIf="paramForm">
        <div class="col-sm-4 padding-top-30" *ngFor="let reportParam of formData">
          <label>{{ reportParam.name | textTrimmer }}</label>
          <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reportParam.type === 'Date'? dateField: textField"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{reportParam: reportParam}">
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<ng-template #textField let-reportParam="reportParam">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input #inputField type="text" [name]="reportParam.name" class="form-control"
      placeholder="{{ 'vrvReportTranslation.item' | cxTranslate }}" (change)="inputChanged(reportParam)" />
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #dateField let-reportParam="reportParam">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input #inputField type="text" [name]="reportParam.name" class="form-control ng-datepicker" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"
      ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" (dateSelect)="d1.toggle();" [positionTarget]="buttonFrom"
      [formControlName]="reportParam.name" (change)="inputChanged(reportParam)" [firstDayOfWeek]="7" />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi-calendar3 margin-0" #buttonFrom (click)="d1.toggle();" type="button"
      [ngClass]="'active-btn'">
      <span class="calendar-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And my component file looks like this:

```
  formData: ReportsParam[] = [];
  paramForm: FormGroup | undefined;
  filteredParam$ = this.reportService.getReportParams();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredParam$.subscribe(data => {
      // update the array in case subscription triggers again
      this.formData.length = 0;
      let formObj: { [key: string]: FormControl } = {};
      const previousMonthDate = this.getLastMonthDate();
      console.log(this.paramForm);
      if (data)
        data.forEach(element => {
          formObj[element.name] = this.formBuilder.control('');
          this.formData.push(element);
        })
      this.paramForm = this.formBuilder.group(formObj);
      console.log(this.paramForm);
    });
  }
```

Below is the error I am getting

[image: Error message]

I understand the error is happening because paramForm is getting its value after the view has been created thus throwing this error, but I am not able to solve this. I don't know:

1. How to resolve the error, checking if formObject has values doesn't solve the issue.
2. Is it even the best/correct approach to create a dynamic form for an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. If you are using ng-container for formGroup you need to tell the templates which formgroup you want to use. So the template should look like this :

```
    <div class="padding-top-50" *ngIf="filteredParam$ | async; else loader">
      <form class="row" [formGroup]="paramForm">
        <div class="col-sm-4 padding-top-30" *ngFor="let reportParam of formData">
          <label>{{ reportParam.name | textTrimmer }}</label>
          <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reportParam.type === 'Date'? dateField: textField"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{reportParam: reportParam}">
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>
<ng-template #textField let-reportParam="reportParam">
  <div class="input-group" [formGroup]="paramForm">
    <input #inputField type="text" [name]="reportParam.name" class="form-control"
      placeholder="{{ 'vrvReportTranslation.item' | cxTranslate }}" (change)="inputChanged(reportParam)" />
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #dateField let-reportParam="reportParam">
  <div class="input-group" [formGroup]="paramForm">
    <input #inputField type="text" [name]="reportParam.name" class="form-control ng-datepicker" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"
      ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" (dateSelect)="d1.toggle();" [positionTarget]="buttonFrom"
      [formControlName]="reportParam.name" (change)="inputChanged(reportParam)" [firstDayOfWeek]="7" />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi-calendar3 margin-0" #buttonFrom (click)="d1.toggle();" type="button"
      [ngClass]="'active-btn'">
      <span class="calendar-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Rest all the things will be same. Also one *ngIf was not required. Not marking this as answer because it doesn't answer the second part, i.e. Is it even the best/correct approach to create a dynamic form for an API.